# Preposition between verb and l'air

Tags: prépositions

it's been bothering me for quite a while, but I still can't make up my mind on what would be the proper way to say: "to do something in a (adj) way" using the word l'air Eg: she is knitting thoughtfully. I think we should use avec l'air  (adj) but I'm not quite sure
Could you please help me? Thanks

Comment: *Avec l'air* or [*avoir l'air*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/avoir-l-air?q=avoir+l%27air) could not be used to translate [thoughtfully](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/thoughtfully). Since the site is not meant to do translations ([please read the Help centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), could you make the question clearer. Knitting is not an action I would associate with "being thoughtful" so I'm wondering what you really mean by ["thoughtfully"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thoughtfully).

Comment: Would you mean to use  *l'air pensif* ? (*Elle tricotait, l'air pensif.*)

Answer (score 1):

**I**

If the context is that of someone lost in thought while doing something then,
the   usual preposition "avec" can be used.

- Elle est en train de tricoter avec un air pensif. • Elle est en train de tricoter avec l'air pensif. (*There is no significant difference between the use of a definite or an indefinite article.*)

But you can do away with a preposition and use an apposition; if this is the chosen syntax, you can't use  the indefinite article, though; you must use the definite article "le".

- Elle est en train de tricoter, l'air pensif.

**II**

If the context is that of someone doing something with care, delicately (as in the example from English literature below (1)), then it's a bit different: you can't use the word "air" but you can use the expression "l'air de *faire qqc*".

- Slowly, thoughtfully, Justine took another helping of spaghetti. (Mistletoe Man
  https://books.google.fr  books
  ) (1)
- Elle est en train de tricoter avec soin.
- Elle est en train de tricoter avec l'air d'y mettre du soin.

Comment: Three questions: 1) Would the "gentiment/avec prévenance" sense of "thoughtfully" (He thoughtfully knitted scarves for all of us) fall under one of your two sections?... 2) Since OP seems to [also] be asking whether "avec" is the right (the only?) preposition to place between the [verb] and "l'air [adj]," mightn't s/he be interested in knowing that "**d**'un air" is also a possibility? ... 3) Shouldn't the OP be "warned" that using "[verb] de/avec un/l'air [adj]" instead of a simple adverb **could** imply that the actor is just pretending to be [whatever adjective] for the sake of appearances?

Comment: @PapaPoule 1) No, so as to render this idea some other expression, in which "air" can't be of any use, is needed. (e.g.: Plein d'attentions pour nous tous, il nous tricotait de plaisantes écharpes.) 2) That is an interesting remark, and I did think about it but neglected mentioning it for the reason that it is raises some incertitudes. As I see it, "d'un/de l'" is used when the appearence, which can be literally facial expression or figuratively  a particular quality of an enonciation, is directly tied in to what is being said or also what is being done. (1/3)

Comment: @PapaPoule (e,g.:  D'un/avec un air de ne pas vouloir lui parler, le responsable laissait d'habitude tomber sur le bureau de Jean  les papiers que celui-ci avait  à travailler. •  Elle lui soupirait des choses douces à l'oreille [avec / d'] un air de ne pas y toucher.) 3) I do no agree with your possible interpretation de "lair de mettre"; there is an implication that I do not pinpoint (2/3)

Comment: @PapaPoule  though, but it  concerns the  locutor's perception at large: s/he perceives what in her/his eye looks like what is asserted but no judgement is to be inferred as to the sincerity of the observable behaviour; more will have to be said. The perception might be that of a meretricious attitude or it could be a misintrepation of the  signs, just a figment of the imagination, but unless that is made sufficiently precise in what follows (or precedes) the listener takes it in at face value. (3/3)